# C Assembly : Return value from %eax beyond jump instruction error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

In following c function

#1

```
int check()
{
__asm__ __volatile__ (
   <snip some activity that has a jump to not_supported>
   "movl $1, %eax \n\t"       \
   "jmp done \n\t"            \
"not_supported:\n\t"          \
   "movl $0, %eax \n\t"       \
“done:\n\t”
 );
}
```

Return value is stored in the `eax` register

This compiles fine on
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
But complains in other place due to werror enforcement

```
error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]
```

So to make it acceptable to gcc with `werror` I added a stack variable as a return value to #1

```
 int check()
 {
   int ret_value =0;

__asm__ __volatile__ (
         <snip some activity that has a jump to not_supported>
         "movl $1, %0 \n\t" : "=a"(ret_value) ::  \
         "jmp done \n\t"                          \
"not_supported:\n\t"                              \
         "movl $0, %0 \n\t" : "=a"(ret_value) ::  \
 "done:\n\t"
  );
 
 return ret_value;
}
```

The gcc doesn’t allow this to compile even with non werror case :

```
: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token 
    "movl $0, %0 \n\t" : "=r"(ret_value) :: \
```

This complains at the first : in the `movl` instruction

I tried with the `“=r”` register operand constraints for output as well but still it doesn’t compile. I also tried explicitly giving clobber registers as "eax" but that also doesn't help.
It seems gcc complains about `ret_value` modification after the `jmp` .

Other thing I tried was #1 with another `mov` from `eax` to `ret_val` which logically didn’t make sense to me.
(What I mean is adding a `movl` instruction after the `done:` that moves value of `%eax` to `%0` which is `ret_val`)
And that didn’t compile either.

Any thing I am missing here ?

Comment: You need to use the [proper syntax for inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). The output operands of the assembly template must be specified once, for the whole template. Be sure to use the right output specifier (either output in `r/eax` and use `=a` or, better, let the compiler pick up a register with `=r`). Finally, don't forget the clobbers.

Comment: For a longer function, consider using regular assembly instead of inline assembly.

Comment: @MargaretBloom This is one of those things that I've read at least 4 times and still don't understand. I seem to run into that a lot with programming.

Comment: In your first block, `“done:\n\t”` is using non-ASCII quotes. That probably won't compile.  The colour syntax highlighting draws extra attention to that.  Same problem with `“=r”` in the text at one point.

Comment: Have you considered `xor %eax,%eax` / set FLAGS / `setz %al` instead of branching (Or ending with `setz %al` and telling the compiler it's an 8-bit output, or manually using `setz %cl` ; `movzbl %cl, %eax`)?  Or using GCC6 condition-code output operands instead of materializing a boolean in a register.  (This is separate from the syntax error of trying to put an output operand in the middle of the template string, instead of at the end where it goes to describe the "black box" code to the compiler.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@margaretBloom's suggestion helped. I removed multiple mentions of output operands and just kept one at the end. This helped compile but here's the disassembled output looks like :

```
  0x000055555555519f <+53>: jmp    0x5555555551a6 <dummy_funct+60>
   0x00005555555551a1 <+55>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00005555555551a6 <+60>:    mov    %edx,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00005555555551a9 <+63>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x00005555555551ac <+66>:    pop    %rbp
   0x00005555555551ad <+67>:    retq
```

Here the compiler is trying to write the stack variable contents to eax . Thus overwriting the real output that was originally stored in the eax.

With further exploration and bug fixes following thing works :

```
   "movl $1, %%eax \n\t"  \
   "movl %%eax, %0 \n\t"  \
   "jmp done \n\t"   \
not_supported:\n\t" \
   "movl $0, %%eax \n\t"  \
   "movl %%eax, %0 \n\t"  \
"done:\n\t"          \
   : "=r" (ret_value)
   :
   :"%eax", "%ebx", "%ecx"
);
```

The trick was to record the results in the eax and then copy those to the return value explicitly along with appropriate clobbering. The other thing was provided register operands rather than the registers themselves for the instructions.

Comment: Yup, that's the right syntax.  The code inside the template is rather inefficient: that use of `%%eax` is pointless.  `mov $1, %0` or `xor %0,%0` if you're branching anyway.  Using `eax` as one of the clobbers means the compiler can't pick it as `%0`, so `return ret_value` will require the compiler to emit yet another `mov` after the ones you wrote, to copy to EAX, from the register it picked for `"=r"`.